# How to fire "change" event on "Additional CSS Class" input

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using JS to populate the Additional CSS Class input, which works fine (i.e. the value of the text input field is getting set), however it's not notifying Gutenberg that the value has been updated, and it doesn't save the programmatically-populated value. I've tried:

```
classField.trigger( 'change' );
classField.trigger( 'input' );
```

...which do fire but have no effect on Gutenberg. Any ideas?

*UPDATE (not working yet)

```
wp.domReady( function() {

jQuery('body').on( 'change', '.acf-field[data-name=col_size] select', function() {
  var clientId = jQuery(".wp-block.is-selected").attr("data-block");
  wp.data.dispatch( 'acf/column' ).updateBlockAttributes( clientId, { className:'my-style' } );
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the blocks `className` attribute, using the target blocks `clientId`, dispatch a call to WordPress to save the change via:

```js
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlockAttributes( clientId, { className:'my-style' } );
```

The `clientId` is stored in the `data-block` value of the rendered HTML, eg. Table Block:

```html
<figure 
    ... 
    data-block="{clientId}" 
    data-type="core/table" 
    data-title="Table"
>
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/

Comment: Thank you.  I get a concole error:
"wp.data.dispatch(...) is null"  - Any Idea?

Comment: @Benmay It will return a [Promise until the dispatch call resolves](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#dispatch), if you are checking immediately, you may see null, await the Promise..

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to make it work.
I have a custom backend_script.js file where it should simply add a value to the Gutenberg Additional CSS Class field on a click for example.  I am problably missing something.

Comment: @Benmay Have you enqueued your backend_script.js via [enqueue_block_assets](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_assets/) so it is loaded in the Editor?

Comment: yes I did.  I updated my initial post with the current js code I got.  Maybe you'll se some issues there

Comment: @Benmay In your example, you still need `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' )` as the Block Editor issues the dispatch to the block based on `clientId`.  I would also check the ACF block supports className? If it doesn't, it won't update. Alternative explaination if it still doesnt update, the PHP block rendering could be overriding the className.